# Why SVD left singular vectors computed with Eigen and OpenCV have different signs

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, math, eigen

I am using both OpenCV and Eigen to calculate SVD:

```
Eigen:
JacobiSVD<Matrix3f> svd(myM, ComputeFullU);

OpenCV:
cvSVD(&myM, &w, &u, 0, CV_SVD_MODIFY_A | CV_SVD_U_T);
```

I am focused on the left singular vectors:

```
Eigen result:
 0.0341698  -0.064916   0.997306
  0.950241  -0.307051 -0.0525437
  0.309635   0.949476   0.051194

OpenCV result:
[0.03417001163639093, -0.06491612525262211, 0.9973055233913801;
  -0.9502414121501213, 0.3070511298822651, 0.05254390804810754;
  -0.3096347347112595, -0.9494764348419663, -0.05119404985032185]
```

Despite that one is float type and another is double type, the calculated left singular vectors have different signs. So my question are:

1. Does this difference of sign really matter?
2. How to make them the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, it does not matter, since a corresponding sign difference will appear also on the right singular vectors, so basically

   ```
   U * S * V^adjoint
   ```

   will give you the right result.

   More precisely, from Wikipedia:

   > Non-degenerate singular values always have unique left- and
   >   right-singular vectors, up to multiplication by a unit-phase factor
   >   `exp(iφ)` (for the real case up to sign). Consequently, if all singular      > values of M are non-degenerate and non-zero, then its singular value
   >   decomposition is unique, up to multiplication of a column of U by a
   >   unit-phase factor and simultaneous multiplication of the corresponding
   >   column of V by the same unit-phase factor.
2. Why would you want them identical? If you really want, you can get the phase by dividing the first components, then make them equal by multiplying by that phase.
3. An additional difference may also appear due to ordering of the singular values, afaik eigen orders them in decreasing order, not sure about opencv.

Answer (score 3):

Singular Value decomposition is not unique, there are multiple possible decompositions. The actual set of singular values is unique, but the left and right matrices of vectors can have different signs, and it wouldn't matter as multiple combinations  signs could cancel out.

An obvious example, for `M = UΣV*`, decompose like `M=(-U)Σ(-V*) = UΣV*` but in general you can have different sign combinations for the left and right singular vectors.

This difference does not really matter so I don't think you should bother trying to make them the same.

Not only that but the order of the singular vectors can also vary. Normally it is in descending order of singular values.